# Avoiding circular template

Tags: c++, templates

I am unit-testing a class `TestingThis`, containing a socket which is templated on `TestingThis` (for callbacks):

```
class TestingThis
{
    TestingThis() : _socket(*this){}

    Socket<SocketType, TestingThis> _socket;
};
```

However, for unit testing I'd like to mock the socket, so make the socket type a template parameter of `TestingThis`:

```
template<class SOCKET>
class TestingThis
{
    TestingThis() : _socket(*this){}

    SOCKET _socket;
};
```

but because the production socket is already templated on `TestingThis`, when I instantiate `TestingThis` it will have an infinite recursion in the template parameters:

```
TestingThis<Socket<SocketType, TestingThis<Socket<.......repeats forever......>>>> productionInstance;

                                               ^ this is the problem
```

What's the best way to handle this?

UPDATE

Okay I've managed to get to a point where I can do:

```
TestingThis<Socket, NoSSL> production;
TestingThis<Socket, OpenSSL> production;
TestingThis<Socket, AnotherSSL> production;
```

However, for testing the implementation doesn't really matter and it would make more sense to instantiate like this:

```
TestingThis<MockSocket> testing;
```

with production passing the socket implementation as a further parameter:

```
TestingThis<Socket<NoSSL>> production;
TestingThis<Socket<OpenSSL>> production;
TestingThis<Socket<AnotherSSL>> production;
```

Comment: What's wrong with making socket's parameters as `typename SocketType` and `template<class> class TestingThis`?

Comment: If you want to mock `Socket`, then why not `template<template<typename...> class Socket> class TestingThis { /*...*/ Socket<SocketType, TestingThis> _socket; };` and then pass the mock `Socket` class template as template argument?

Comment: @lorro I've got it working where I instantiate like this: `TestingThis<Socket, SocketImpl>`. However, if I wanted to instantiate like: `TestingThis<Socket<SocketImpl>>` would that be possible or is that a template template...... template parameter? I'd like to achieve this because for testing I can just do `TestingThis<MockSocket>`

Comment: @user17732522 My previous comment is probably a question to you too, as I think you suggested the same as lorro?

Comment: @user997112 It is really unclear to me what _exactly_ you are mocking. Is it `Socket` or `SocketType` or what? If you are mocking `Socket`, then the mock should also dependent on `SocketType`, shouldn't it? If you mock `SocketType`, then you don't need to replace `Socket`?

Comment: @user17732522 I've just clarified the question in the update with what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't have the template `Socket` take only one argument as at the end of your edit, but then have it "add-on" the argument `TestingThis` as in the first code snippet. To achieve this separation of the template arguments you would need to make `Socket` a class template depending on only one template parameter, containing a `template<typename OtherParam> struct type { /*...*/ };` member with the actual implementation and then the class would need to use `typename Socket::template type<TestingThis> _socket;`. That's not really more readable in my opinion.

Comment: `MockSocket` can just take the `SocketType` as template argument and ignore it to mimic the interface of `Socket` faithfully. You can also reorder the template parameters and use default arguments to avoid having to spell the `Socket` argument in production all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance can be used sometimes to shoehorn recursive dependencies into each other. The following scaffolding compiles without issues:

```
struct SocketType;

template<typename, typename> class Socket {

public:
    template<typename Arg> Socket(Arg &arg) {}
};

//************************************************************

struct SocketImpl;

template<typename T=SocketImpl> class TestingThis : public T
{
public:
    TestingThis() : T{*this} {}
};

struct SocketImpl {

    Socket<SocketType, TestingThis<>> _socket;

    SocketImpl(TestingThis<> &parent) : _socket{parent}
    {
    }
};

TestingThis<> for_real;
```

For unit testing create a different subclass, with a mock socket.

Alternatively: an instance of `T` can be a class member, rather than a superclass.